# Asp.net Core List<enum> in model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, enums, asp.net-core

I'm trying to include a list of enums in my model, however I'm encountering some issues. In my first approach I tried this:

```
public class Ferrata
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Id")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "PlaceName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public double Lat { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public double Lon { get; set; }

    public string GeoLat { get { return Lat.ToString(); } }

    public string GeoLong { get { return Lon.ToString(); } }

    public List<Difficulty> Difficulty { get; set; }
}

public enum Difficulty { F, PD, AD, D, TD, ED };
```

However using enum in such way results with an exception when I try to perform any operation with ef:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'Ferrata.Difficulty'
>   could not be mapped, because it is of type 'List' which is
>   not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type. Either
>   explicitly map this property, or ignore it.

Following some advice on the internet, I created a standalone class for holding my enum values like this:

```
public class FerrataDifficulty
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Difficulty Difficulty { get; set; }

    public FerrataDifficulty(Difficulty difficulty)
    {
        Difficulty = difficulty;
    }
}
```

After changing my original Ferrata class to take list of FerrataDifficulty the program compiles, however there are two problems:
* Even though in my database initializer I initialize the difficulties when I debug the code they seem to be null
* When I try to delete the database entries through the application I get the following error:

> SqlException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_FerrataDifficulty_Ferrata_FerrataID". The conflict occurred in database "ViaFerrata1", table "dbo.FerrataDifficulty", column 'FerrataID'.

I would appreciate if anyone could point out what I'm doing wrong and what's the best practice on including a list of enums in the model in asp.net core.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you provided. You need to post the code actually causing the errors. You also need to tell us what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: You can't use "Difficulty" als entity, because only classes with an can be entities. Make it a class with an Id (or use shadow property) and a property for the difficulty and then map it. Or turn the enum as a flag and use it as a non-collection property `public Difficulty Difficulty { get; set; }` if you want to store more than one of it

Comment: if the Difficulty enum is string you need to provide enum type as string but its better to use static class with public string constants or give the enum a type (int, short, string ... etc) and allow it to be convertible as required since you should think of it as a custom type not as automatic built-in type

Comment: Consider a [nameof](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof) operator.

Comment: @Tseng you were right about Difficulties needing to be an entity (hence requiring it's own class, and an ID property). Since doing that seemed like a bit of an overkill I went ahead with enum flags. I will update my post to reflect this change now.

Comment: Don't post solutions in the question, post it as answer

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve the problem by using enum flags:

```
[Flags]
[JsonConverter(typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter))]
public enum Difficulty
{
    F = 1,
    PD = 2,
    AD = 4,
    D = 8,
    TD = 16,
    ED = 32
};
```

This seems to be the simplest way to achieve exactly what I needed.