# List<Enum> could not be mapped

Tags: c#, entity-framework, enums, .net-core

I have models in my .Net Core project where I want to have a List of Enum.

```
public class CartOptional
    {
        [Required]
        public Guid Id { get; private set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public string CartId { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public List<FieldValidator> Validators { get; set; }
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

FieldValidator is indeed an Enum

EF return me this error :

> The property 'CartOptional.Validators' could not be mapped, because it is of type 'List' which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type. Either explicitly map this property, or ignore it using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

I tried different solution like adding `[Serializable]`. But nothing seems to work. I don't understand why the system cannot take the underliying `int`

EDIT:

I tried the solution with `[Flags]` annotation like so

```
[Flags]
public enum FieldValidator
{
    REQUIRED = 1,
    ALPHABETIC = 2,
    NUMERIC = 4,
    EMAIL = 8,
    PHONE = 16,
    DATE = 32
}
```

And in the parent class I have `public FieldValidator Validators { get; set; }`

But now I try to POST a new element and I got this error when I try to validate the `ModelState`:

> "tierList[0].fieldList[0].validators": [
>           "Unexpected token StartArray when parsing enum. Path 'tierList[0].fieldList[0].validators', line 24, position 25."
>       ]

What is a `token StartArray` ?

Comment: why you are try to List<Enum>? explain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asp.net Core List<enum> in model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45789635/asp-net-core-listenum-in-model)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28429945/ef-property-of-type-listenum-not-created-in-db

Comment: Why use the `Serializable` attribute? The error says the problem is with the type itself. What is `FieldValidator`? Unless it's an *entity* mapped to another table, EF won't know what to do with it. Does it represent 5 columns in the table? A single `int` that's used as a bitfield? Something else?

Comment: @ershoaib Because this attribute can have one or N attribute in that list.

Comment: @RuiJarimba first solution tested. Doesn't seems to work.

Comment: @Ragnar then it's not an attribute at all. Multiple values means multiple *rows*. What does the *table* for that entity look like? Where would you expect to store the FieldValidator values?

Comment: @Ragnar if the enum is a *Flag*, the property shouldn't be a `List<FiledValidator>`, it should be `public FieldValidator Validators { get; set; }`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm thinkig to much in a NoSQL like. I cannot have a list of something in a row int the SQL world. I have to rethink my model.

Comment: you can use Enum[]

Answer (score 6):

**The problem is not enum at all. It is the List**. You would get the same error even if you tried

```
public List<int> Validators { get; set; }
```

or

```
public List<string> Validators { get; set; }
```

or any other type.

**This is not even a restriction of EF, but rather the database itself**. You are trying to add a list of values in a table column. The databases I know don't have a configuration for such a thing.

If you want to attach a list of values in a database table, the way is to create a new table (possible a new Look Up Table in your case) that holds a foreign key to `CartOptional`. Something like this:

```
public class FieldValidatorEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int CartOptionalId { get; set; }
    public CartOptional CartOptional { get; set; }

    public FieldValidator Value { get; set; }
    // other columns
}
```

And use this property in your `CartOptional` entity:

```
public List<FieldValidatorEntity> Validators { get; set; }
```

A workaround would be to make `Validators` a string property and hold something like comma separated values, or even try a byte array if it suits you. Databases can store byte arrays in a column.

Hope I could help,
merry coding!

Comment: For the Enum I use the `[Flag]` attribute but this is the approach I did for my other list. Like I said I come from a NoSQL (Mongo mainly) world. I have to remember this difference.

Comment: Postgres has been able to define array columns since the year 2000 or so.
Most other major database engines can store arrays via JSON columns.

Answer (score 1):

One `Enum` value shouldn't be an issue, but since the Enum is just an integer value, you cannot use it as (a list of) entities. You should either explicitly make the Enum an entity, or use a Flags Enum instead (which I would recommend).

Have a look at [Working with Enumerated Values in Entity Framework](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/02/01/enumerated-values.aspx), for instance.

Comment: Storing bitfields in table is a problem in itself as they *can't* be indexed or queried.

Comment: That's why I also suggested to _either explicitly make the Enum an entity, or use a Flags Enum instead_ ;)